# internal error undefined index

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am getting internal error

```
in AdminController.php line 85
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: name', 'C:\wamp64\www\laravel\dev.oasis-portal.my\app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php', '85', array('data' => array())) in AdminController.php line 85
```

when I run

```
public function courseDelete()
  {
    $data = Input::all();

    $student = Course::where('name', '=', $data["name"]);

    if($student->delete()) {

      User::find($data["name"])->delete();

      return json_encode(array('success' => true));

    } else {

      return json_encode(array('success' => false, 'errors' => "Unable to remove student."));
    }
  }
```

My route is:    Route::get('/course/delete/', 'AdminController@courseDelete');

Comment: `$data["name"]` is undefined. Ensure that your input data isset or validate it with `isset($data["name"])`.

Comment: how can I set it?  $scope.items = items;
            $scope.ok = function() {
              
             
              $data = {
               id: name
              };

Comment: Please read the basics of using PHP/AngularJS. You can't access AngularJS variables in PHP directly. The error you show is thrown in PHP. This is not depending on AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

`$data["name"]` is not set, and therefore an exception is thrown. A better solution would be to get parameters by using the `request()` shorthand:

ie. `request()->get('name'); //will return null if not set`